# Converting Jreport to CSV to Excel generating excessive blank columns

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I'm using MasterControl to create JReports and am having to convert the reports into CSVs and opening in Excel. For some reason, during the process, there are several blank columns that are being generated after the populated columns (the last column from the JReport is column "F", but blank columns are generated all the way out to "BSY"). I've created a bit of VBA code that will automatically hide the blank columns, but does anyone know what might be the issue? I have a duplicate that only has a single filter changed and it is being converted by Excel just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. When downloading the JReport through MasterControl, you need to deselect the "Use Quote Mark" option, as this will cause Excel to not know where to stop creating columns when using tab delimiters.